# Tell in C# that a genericly passed interface extends another interface with a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, interface, extends

How could I tell in C# that a genericly passed interface extends another interface, which also has a generic parameter?

E.g. how can I tell that the `Y` has a `foo` method?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new BImplementation();
        var c = new C<B>();
        c.bar(b);
    }
}

public interface A<T> {
    T foo();
}

public interface B : A<int> {}
public class BImplementation : B {
    public int foo() => 2;
}

public class C<Y> /*where Y : A<T>*/ {
    public void bar(Y y)  {
        //I would like to be able to call y.foo here
        //how can I do that?
        //I need to somehow describe the Y type parameter, 
        //that the Y actually has the `T foo()` method from `A<T>
        
        //y.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class C<Y, T> where T : A<T>`? `C` needs to be generic over both the type of the interface, and the return type of `foo`. How else would you write `T result = y.foo()`?

Comment: @canton7, should I delete my question?